# Swift UIRefreshControl to UICollectionView inside UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have UICollectioview inside UIScrollView and I want to add UIRefreshControl, but it don't work

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.folderCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.folderCollectionView.bounces  = true
        self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.folderCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}


@objc
    private func didPullToRefresh(_ sender: Any) {
        print("123")
        getFolder(update: true)
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

In getFolder I get data and reload collection

When I run collection don't have pull to update and don't work

What have I done wrong

Comment: set refreshcontrol to your scrollview not to your folderCollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UIRefreshControl` to the `UICollectionView` using this way, see the following code, I hope it helps you.

```
// Add Refresh Control to Collection View
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    folderCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    folderCollectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Comment: Edit your function like "@objc func didPullToRefresh(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {}" , remove private keyword and change type any to UIRefreshControl